# Fetch webpage data and check for a particular text using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to fetch data from a webpage and search for a particular text in it. I am able to do it using python but i want to do it using javascript. I am attaching the python code so that you can understand what i am trying to do, and how I can do it using javascript.

```
import requests
a = requests.get("http://localhost:3000/data")
b = a.text
if("wrong" in b):
  print(b)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regex search in javascript like so

```js
fetch('http://google.com')
    .then(function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            // status "OK"
            case 200:
                let text = response.text();
                let n = text.search("W3Schools");
                console.log(text,n)
            // status "Not Found"
            case 404:
                throw response;
        }
    })
    .then(function (template) {
        console.log(template);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // "Not Found"
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });
```

Comment: But should I fetch data from the webpage(http://localhost:3000/data)

Comment: @aryan i modified the snippet but it will not work with cross-site domains on browsers.

Comment: I will take care of it